# Project management methods fix requirements in an effort to control time and cost

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Isn't this usage of the word "fix" ambiguous?

> Project management methods **fix** requirements in an effort to control time and cost. (here the supposed meaning of "fix" is: "settle", "specify", "agree in advance")

Is there a better choice to use in a project management contex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set would be unambiguous:

> Project management methods sets requirements in an effort to control time and cost.

I believe fix would be understood to be a synonym to set, but it could also be interpreted as saying that project management corrects (fixes) bad requirements and makes them better.